# I got a "Blue in the face" hat - why?

Tags: support, winter-bash, winter-bash-2016

So I got a "Blue in the face" hat.

I am not sure why. I posted a wrong comment and deleted it right after when I realised that it was wrong. Is that it?

Furthermore, I'm not sure what it means. Is it good or bad? Blue in the face... hmmm...

Comment: [Winter Bash 2016 - All Hats](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288271/242209)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a secret hat, which you obtain by

> posting at least 10 comments during Winter Bash which each receive at least one upvote.

[(source)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288284/295232)

Hats generally encourage positive behaviour, so you don't need to worry if you did something bad.

Comment: Ahh - I see. Makes sense as I also posted a comment that got one upvoted. But what does it mean? Blue in the face.... I got no clue

Comment: @4386427 [It's an idiom](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/blue+in+the+face).  It means you talk so  much that you don't breathe.