# Is there a list of explanations for the names of hats?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2016

I've been curious about the seemingly esoteric names of some hats, like 925 and 011. And what does December 30th have to do with bacon? I assume they are cute references, but I feel out of the loop.

Apparently [I'm not the only one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340462/i-got-a-blue-in-the-face-hat-why) to be confused by hat names.

Is there any authoritative Q&A or community wiki that explains the hat names?

Comment: Would [this on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288803/a-list-of-what-each-of-the-winter-bash-2016-hats-are-named-after) be close to what you're looking for? It's not authoritative, but it'll likely be updated by an employee later.

Comment: Ah, that is helpful... and it links to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288474/why-are-so-many-hats-named-after-numbers-what-do-the-numbers-mean/288477#288477) which touches on 925 and 011. I'll add those to the community wiki

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The best answer appears to be this community wiki on Meta Stack Exchange:

[A list of what each of the Winter Bash 2016 hats are named after](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288803/a-list-of-what-each-of-the-winter-bash-2016-hats-are-named-after/288809#288809)